# returning one item at a time from ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a large list of objects that I have created in my WebMethod, which takes fairly long to load.

I was wondering if anyone had an example of pulling one item at a time allowing my ajax to display each object as soon as they get it, making them see part of the data faster(even tho it may be slower in the long run)

thanks.

Comment: then don't return all the data once!

Comment: Haha yes.. but the most efficient way to return it in order is what gets me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to execute a separate ajax request for each item that you're retrieving. Also the `WebMethod` needs to receive as a parameter which item it should return on each request.

Comment: The last part is the tricky part. I need to keep an order, so I don't pull the same thing. but I don't want to grab the entire table in the database each time to figure out what row I am on

Comment: Basically I have a full list, should I only be grabbing one row at a time from the database?

Answer (score 2):

you can use serverside pagination by sending some offset and limit value, following can be reffered

[Link](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)